# Problem regarding width in carousel in react native

Tags: react-native, carousel

I am learning carousel in react native for the first time. I am experiencing error " `width` must be specified for horizontal carousels. "

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components/native";
import Carousel from "react-native-reanimated-carousel";
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Image, Dimensions } from "react-native";
class CourseScreen extends React.Component
 {
_renderItem = ({ item, index }) => 
{
    return (
      <View>
        <Image
         source={{ uri: item.image }}
         style={{ width: "100%", height: 350 }}
        />
      </View>
    );
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        <Carousel
          ref={(c) => {
            this._carousel = c;
          }}
          data={MovieCardData}
          renderItem={this._renderItem}
          sliderWidth={Dimensions.get("screen").width}
          itemWidth={Dimensions.get("screen").width / 3}
        />
      </Container>
    );
  }
}
export default CourseScreen;

const Container = styled.View`
  flex: 1;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
`;

const MovieCardData = [
  {
    image:
      "https://www.animenewsnetwork.com/images/encyc/A4313-23.jpg",
    title: "Sample Picture 1",
  },
  {
    image:
      "https://www.animenewsnetwork.com/images/encyc/A4313-23.jpg",
    title: "Sample Picture 2",
  },
  {
    image:
      "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMWNhMzc2MzMtYzliMS00MTVkLTgwNTgtMTZjMzc5ZDNlNDY1XkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyMjc2Nzg5OTQ@._V1_FMjpg_UX1000_.jpg",
    title: "Sample Picture 3",
  },
  {
    image: "https://www.animenewsnetwork.com/images/encyc/A4313-23.jpg",
    title: "Sample Picture 4",
  },
];
```

Comment: As it says, you need to specify `width` attribute in the carousel.

Answer (score 1):

need to add width, thats all

```
  const width = Dimensions.get('window').width;

  return (
   ...
   <Carousel
      ref={(c) => {
        this._carousel = c;
      }}
      width={width}
      data={MovieCardData}
      renderItem={this._renderItem}
      sliderWidth={Dimensions.get("screen").width}
      itemWidth={Dimensions.get("screen").width / 3}
    />
    ...
```